# PostgreSQL get_records SQL pseudo API function

Tags: postgresql, function

I'm trying to write simple pseudo-API function with simply query table using any available column as attribute.

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE card (
    id varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    type varchar(5) NOT NULL,
    id_client int4 NULL,
    active bool NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    issue_date date NULL,
    valid_date date NULL,
    temp bool NULL DEFAULT false)
```

Now I want to have a function. Each of attributes should be optional.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_cards(id varchar,type varchar,id_client int,active bool,issue_date date, valid_date date, temp bool)
RETURNS TABLE (id varchar,type varchar,id_client int,active bool,issue_date date, valid_date date, temp bool) AS
$$
BEGIN
 RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM card WHERE id like $1 AND type like $2 AND [etc.]
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This should be valid for query like:

```
select get_card('','',17,False,'','','')
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are coming from Oracle, null and empty strings are not the same in PostgreSQL.

If having empty strings represent missing parameters is what you really want, then:

```
select *
  from card
 where ($1 = '' or id = $1)
   and ($2 = '' or type = $2)
   ...
```

If you want nulls or empty strings to represent missing parameters:

```
select *
  from card
 where (nullif($1, '') is null or id = $1)
   and (nullif($2, '') is null or type = $2)
   ...
```

Siweq reported that he followed the suggestion using `nullif()` calls and received an error regarding type mismatches when calling it as `select get_cards()`.

If that is how this is to be used, then drop the `nullif()` calls and do as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_cards(id varchar,type varchar,id_client int,active bool,issue_date date, valid_date date, temp bool)
    RETURNS TABLE (id varchar,type varchar,id_client int,active bool,issue_date date, valid_date date, temp bool) AS
    $$
    BEGIN
     RETURN QUERY 
     SELECT * FROM card c
        WHERE 1=1
        AND ($1 IS NULL OR c.id = $1)
        AND ($2 IS NULL OR c.type = $2)
        AND ($3 IS NULL OR c.id_client = $3)
        AND ($4 IS NULL OR c.active = $4)
        AND ($5 IS NULL OR c.issue_date = $5)
        AND ($6 IS NULL OR c.valid_date = $6)
        AND ($7 IS NULL OR c.temp = $7)
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: There is no need to reference parameters by numbers, that's why they have names. So you can replace `$1` with `id`